# Same build doesn't work on 2 different identical environments

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, web

I'm running out of options as to what this could be, hence my question here.
I have a big dashboard type website at my company.

- The build works on the Dev invironment.
- The build is deployed to a Dev environment and a Production environment
- The 2 environments are identical in OS and Patch level.
- The entire code base deployed to both servers are 100% alike (as this is deployed through
  TeamCity and the build is promoted from dev to prod.)
- Ive changed web.config on prod to use the same connectionStrings (so DB issues could be ruled out)
- The ApplicationPools are also 100% identical - .NET 4 - integrated

The part that is failing is a model which gets its data from an SQL table, but apparently returns null (on the production environment, NOT on the dev environment)

It is only 1 view with a certain model that is failing with a null reference exception, and only on the production server, everything else works fine, all connections are fine - nothing .

An earlier build on the Production Servers works just fine (no errors) - and nothing has been changed to the site where the error resides.

Anyone with any good ideas?

I have a hard time believing this could be coding issues.
But in my opinion, developers are the ones with the most experience with this sort of thing, hence me posting this question here.

I cannot, for the life of me figure out what could be left for me to try.

NB:
The line that fails is

```
@if (Model.ShowTsm && Model.ShowCv)
```

with:
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The stacktrace:

```
 System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +142
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +383
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +970660
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +956732
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: Do you have the same versions of SQL Server in both environments?  I just had this problem yesterday.  In dev, I had SQL 2012 and prod was SQL 2008R2.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried connecting both to the same exact db - problem persists.

Comment: Is the application pool running under a machine account or a user account?

Comment: For your model, what are you using?  EF (code first)? or LINQ to SQL or NHiberate, etc?  (some ORMs have external config files)

Comment: Application Pool is running as a "network service"(as far as i remember off the top of my head)  on all of the application pools. and its Linq to SQL - using the Unit of work pattern

Answer (score 1):

I have seen developers add some rather "clever" code before.  There are several things that you will need to eliminate.

I just want to confirm, when you say "identical connection string", that the connection string is using a username and password and not "integrated security".  Because that is not identical.  If it is using a username and password, then proceed (next paragraph).

Second thing to try:  Determine if the code is sending different DB calls, based on host (server) name.  Use "SQL profiler" to sniff (spy-on) the calls to the database during the error.  Open SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), (menu) Tools, SQL Server Profiler, connect to your DB (the one that both servers are now talking to).  On the "Trace Properties" screen, "Use the template" TSQL.  (if that doesn't show much, then switch to the template TSQL_SPs).  [ Run ].  Pause immediately.  Use your app until you are almost at the part that fails (and then un-pause).  Observe the calls that go through from dev vs prod.  I can't exactly tell you what to look for, other-than major differences in parameters or SQL commands.

Third (and less likely). There are SQL connection properties that can be configured on any machine, that are not obvious (or seem hidden). You can use the "Sql Server Configuration Manager (OS: start menu, All programs, SQL Server 2008, Configuration Tools, Sql Server Configuration Manager).  If it is not in your start menu, then you might need get the install disc and add "SQL Client Tools".  Check for any Aliases.  Make sure you are using the same Protocols.

Other (very unlikely) things: 1) You may want to use a memory profiler to see what is loaded into memory.  I have used a few wierd tools to see which DLLs are in memory and their versions.  2) If your developers were born prior to the 90s, then they might be crazy enough to set values in the registry or in a hosts/lmhosts file.

If none of these help, let me know.  I have more ideas, but each is more obscure.  I'd wager that the problem is affected by something in the connection (identity) or params that can be observed in DB calls.

Are your developers still around to ask or is this some legacy code?

Comment: ConnectionStrings are with Username/pw - Same DB calls - no code was added to this particular view / controller since last build (which works on dev and prod) - The weird thing about this is that; A: Nothing was changed to this part of the site. B: The older build works. C: Works in Dev but not Prod. - feel free to add any thoughts you might have on what this could be.